# Taking only a single data set from a multiple imputation?

Tags: data-imputation, multiple-imputation

If I use a package like R's `mice` to do multiple imputation, then only select the first of the resulting imputations and use that as a single imputation -- ignoring the rest of the imputations -- am I going to run into problems? (As compared to a single-imputation method.)

The reason I'm considering this is that I'm writing some R code that does some calculations, including an optional imputation step, before handing data off to some other code that cannot (yet) handle multiple data sets. My thinking is that I'd like to use R's `mice` eventually, so why not use it as a single-imputation method for now and then (its intended) multiple-imputation when the downstream code eventually accepts this.

I'm not totally comfortable with this idea because I worry that MI is meant to introduce variance, which can then be quantified, so perhaps a single-imputation method might be better in this case. (Though I have to admit that single-imputation methods also make me nervous, which is why I want to eventually go with MI.)

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't hand each of the multiple imputations to your downstream code and then combine the outputs from the multiple invocations of the downstream code?

Comment: EdM: Very good thought, I'll look into it. Not sure how easy it will be to tap into the output of downstream code, combine things, and re-inject for even further-downstream. I'd still be interested in statistical answers as well.